# CDC Capture failed with error 217

Tags: sql-server, cdc

after enable CDC for database and tables that I want to capture changes, sql server create 2 jobs cdc.xxxx_capture and CDC.xxxx_cleanup successfully.
the problem is every time start CDC.xxxx_capture failed with this error :

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 217)

but CDC.xxxx_cleanup works fine.

please help to solve this problem

Comment: Ha ha! had a same problem in SQL 2017. Could you solve it? What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: sql 14.0.1000.169

Comment: It is Sql 2017 and it seems to be a bug. I reported it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3145601 . Please upvot it to catch more attention

Comment: There is a workaround here : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3145601 you can check it if it works for you or not

Comment: As Microsoft have now closed the connect site, and migrated 'some' data over, the workaround has been lost. Does anyone know what it was ??  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32895901-cdc-capture-job-stops-after-a-while-in-sql-2017

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by Microsoft in [SQL Server 2017 CU4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4073684)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug in Sql Server 2017. A bug report is here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3145601

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/7046bfdb-a7b7-492c-9942-e5361910cf3c/cdc-collection-agent-fails-after-bulk-insert?forum=ssdsgetstarted) someone had the same problem as you do. Problem occurred after Bulk Insert.

They offered him not to use CDC and replace it with DML triggers.

Comment: I read the article but in my case both table source and destination table are empty, as soon as I start the job I get that error.